# Is there a product identity for $ a\cos\left(\alpha\right)+b\cos\left(\beta\right) $

Tags: trigonometry

The product identity of $ \cos\left(\alpha\right)+\cos\left(\beta\right) $ is $ 2\cos\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right) $

Is there any formula that can generalize to $ a\cos\left(\alpha\right)+b\cos\left(\beta\right) $ ?

Comment: I think the OP asking about $a\cos(x)+b\cos(y)$ where $a\not=b$ and $x\not=y$.

Answer (score 8):

Given that the sum-to-product identities arise from the product-to-sum identities, which in turn arise from the angle sum/difference identities, I'd be very surprised if a general "nice" formula exists, at least in terms of a single product. That being said, if you're willing to allow multiple products then you can write
$$a\cos(\alpha)+b\cos(\beta)=\left(\tfrac{a+b}{2}\right)(\cos(\alpha)+\cos(\beta))+\left(\tfrac{a-b}{2}\right)(\cos(\alpha)-\cos(\beta)),$$
which by the normal sum to product is equal to
$$(a+b)\cos(\tfrac{\alpha+\beta}{2})\cos(\tfrac{\alpha-\beta}{2})+(b-a)\sin(\tfrac{\alpha+\beta}{2})\sin(\tfrac{\alpha-\beta}{2}),$$
which I personally think is pretty nice. Of course, if anyone else comes up with any other nice expressions I'd be happy to see them.

Comment: This one is very nice

Comment: The original equation is much simpler, though.  The derived equation might be of some value if $a=\pm b$$ or $\alpha=\pm\beta$, but in these cases the simplification of the original is obvious.